# Does PHP-CGI security issue (CVE-2012-1823) affect PHP running as regular users with mod_fcgid?

Tags: php, security, php-cgi

Does [this PHP-CGI security issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61910) (CVE-2012-1823) affect PHP when it's running under individual regular-user accounts with mod_fcgid?

The wrapper `.fcgi` script I've been using is:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Comment: worked exploit here http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/05/php-cgi-exploitation-by-example.html to test your own servers with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guys at [LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/495905/), it only affects CGI, not FCGI.